# Convert string enum type to union type of enum values

Tags: typescript, enums

How can I get a union type of a typescript string enum?

```
enum MyEnum {
  A = 'a', // Values are different from keys, so keyof will not help here.
  B = 'b',
}
```

Given an enum type like the one above, how can I get the union type "a" | "b" ?

Comment: Just curios what is the use-case for this. I cannot think of a situation where I would need to type something as `"a"|"b"` instead of the string `enum`

Comment: Yes, a use case would be helpful.  The type `MyEnum` is a subtype of the union you're looking for (`MyEnum` = `MyEnum.A | MyEnum.B` ⊂ `"a"|"b"`) but I can't find a way to coax the supertype out of the type system.  If you can post your use case we can maybe give you a solution that doesn't involve fighting with TypeScript.

Comment: Use case: `const value:MyEnum = 'a'` fails and probably should not...

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir So, do you have any ideas on this?

Answer (score 0):

both are ok

```
type enumValuesToUnion<T> = T extends `${infer R}` ? R :never

type enumValuesToUnion_<T> = `${T}`

type a = enumValuesToUnion<MyEnum>
type b = enumValuesToUnion_<MyEnum>
```

Comment: Hey, can you explain this further?